# Error in linking spring boot and postgreSQL(kotlin)

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, kotlin

I want to pass a table from intellij to postgreSQL using spring boot.
The language used is Kotlin and it is written in gradle.

Information arrives until postman, but not postgreSQL.
Also, no error occurs, so I don't know the cause any more.

Below is my code and dependency.

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/spring
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=1234
```

UserInfo.kt

```
import javax.persistence.*
@Entity
data class UserInfo(
    @Id val id: String,
    var pw: String,
    var name: String,
    var birth: String
)
```

Usercontroller.kt

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct

@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = [DataSourceAutoConfiguration::class])
class UserController {

    private val userMap: MutableMap<String, UserInfo> = mutableMapOf()

    @PostConstruct
    fun init() {
   

        userMap["id1"] = UserInfo("id1", "password1", "Alice", "1001")
        userMap["id2"] = UserInfo("id2", "password2", "Rabit", "1101")
        userMap["id3"] = UserInfo("id3", "password3", "Card", "1201")
    }


    @GetMapping(path = ["/user/{id}"])
    fun getUserInfo(@PathVariable("id") id: String) = userMap[id]

    @GetMapping(path = ["user/all"])
    fun getUserInfoAll() = ArrayList<UserInfo>(userMap.values)


    @PutMapping(path = ["/user/{id}"])
    fun putUserInfo(@PathVariable("id") id: String, @RequestParam("pw") pw: String,
                    @RequestParam("name") name: String, @RequestParam("birth") birth: String) {

        val userInfo = UserInfo(id,pw, name, birth)
        userMap[id] = userInfo
    }


    @PostMapping(path = ["/user/{id}"])
    fun postUserInfo(@PathVariable("id") id: String, @RequestParam("pw") pw: String,
                     @RequestParam("name") name: String, @RequestParam("birth") birth: String){
        val userInfo = userMap[id]
        userInfo?.pw = pw
        userInfo?.name = name
        userInfo?.birth = birth
    }

    @DeleteMapping(path = ["/user/{id}"])
    fun deleteUserInfo(@PathVariable("id") id: String) = userMap.remove(id)

}
```

UserRepository.kt

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.reactive.ReactiveCrudRepository
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository


@Repository
interface UserRepository : ReactiveCrudRepository<UserInfo, String
```

gradle is in the attachment

I think there may be a problem in UserRepository.kt, but I can't find it because there is no error.

Thank you for reading the article. I wish you a nice day.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQBrN.png)

Comment: Why are you disabling the DataSource autoconfiguration? i.e., `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = [DataSourceAutoConfiguration::class])`. That looks like your problem, at a glance. Also, you're not using `UserRepository` anywhere in the controller. Creating `UserInfo` objects isn't going to save entities to your db.

Comment: It's still in the learning stage, so I guess I didn't know well by practicing while watching several examples.
So how should I clear @EnableAutoConfiguration and modify UserRepository??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you don't actually call `save()` method of your `UserRepository`

Try injecting it first:

```kotlin
@Autowired
private lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository
```

And inside `putUserInfo()`

```kotlin
    val userInfo = UserInfo(id,pw, name, birth)
    userRepository.save(userInfo)
```

Pay attention, that you will recieve Mono as a result of `save()`

Comment: @Autowired 
private lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository {
    
    val userInfo = UserInfo(id,pw, name, birth)
    userRepository.save(userInfo)
    
}

Comment: I am still learning, so I am sorry to ask you in detail...
Can I write it like this?

Comment: Just declare `userRepository` as a member of Controller
and then put the second block of code inside your `fun putUserInfo(...)`

Comment: As already warned, type of save has become mono. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Mono is advanced topic. In simplest case you can call its `.block()` to synchronously wait until Mono is resolved

Comment: @user15043386 Are you meaning to use the Reactive data repository over the blocking/non-reactive data repository?